# Block read and write in NOR flash

Tags: linux, hardware, embedded, flash-memory, flash

Actually i am working with NOR flash. I am getting confused about block read and write from NOR flash.

- From my understand block read and write means writing and reading complete sector of the flash. Is it correct? Please anyone help to clarify my doubt.

Comment: If you want to know on a low level, refer to the datasheet of your flash. If you want to use it in your system, simply rely on the driver of your `/dev/mtd` device and use utilities like `flashcp`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about Unix&Linux.

Answer (score 0):

A NOR flash chip may be read-accessed in a random fashion, you do not need to read the whole block.

When it comes to writing, you will *always* have to erase the whole block before writing. The need for erasing before writing is also true for NAND flash chips.